# How to set screen to black

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, projector

I'm looking for a feature that seems impossible to search for due to too many problems with graphics drivers...

I'd like to set the screen to black to disable output on a projector for a moment. The projector doesn't have a feature for this. I also can't use the usual `xset dpms force off` or `xset s activate` because it causes the 'no signal' display on the projector.

A full screen black window would do the job, but is a bit inconvenient to use. There has to be some simple tool for this?

Comment: Hello, why is that inconvienient? Wouldn't using a CLI command that just opens a black image to fullscreen, that you can also set an alias for, just work?

Comment: @Destroy666 With a single or duplicated screen this indeed works well - but with a secondary extended screen one needs to adjust the position of this window (and names and positions on the viewport change depending on which projector is used on which output)